# python overwrite output on same line

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I have the below

```
foo = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
from random import choice
while True:
    print choice(foo)
```

The output is:

```
a
c
a
e
...
```

I want the terminal output to overwrite the old output on the same line

thanks

Comment: Instead of writing backspace characters, I would recommend usind the curses module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two things to override: one, python will automatically add a newline when you `print`.  Override that by adding a comma at the end, like @SteveP says (or said at least :-)).

Next, you need to explicitly add a carriage return control character to the front of your string so that the terminal output will *overwrite* your previous output, as opposed to appending it to the end.

```
foo = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
from random import choice
while True:
    print '\r' + choice(foo),
```

(might want a `time.sleep` in there so you can actually see what's happening)

Answer (score 2):

you can remove the old output by

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write( '\b' ) # removes the last outputed character
```

and you possibly need to use `flush` after each `print`

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

something like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time

for j in range( 10 ):
   print( j, end='' )
   sys.stdout.flush()
   time.sleep( 2 )
   sys.stdout.write( '\b' )
```